# Ubuntu: Gradle maven-publish plugin - Failing to connect by sftp

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, gradle, sftp

I'm trying to get my gradle script to upload to an sftp account, but it keeps failing with error,

> Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.himself12794:Heroes-Mod:jar:0.9-rev1 from/to remote (sftp://himself1@ftp.himself12794-develops.com:18765/public_html/maven): Could not write to resource 'com/himself12794/Heroes-Mod/0.9-rev1/Heroes-Mod-0.9-rev1.jar'

I'm able to connect via sftp command:

```
sftp -P 18765 himself1@ftp.himself12794-develops.com
```

However, the publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository task fails, with the above error.

This is a Minecraft Forge mod, if that sheds any light on things.

My build.gradle is like so:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                name = "forge"
                url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.0-        SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'
    apply plugin: "maven-publish"

    // for people who want stable
    /*plugins {
        id "net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge" version "2.0.1"
        id "maven-publish"
    }*/

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "himself12794-develops"
            url = "http://maven.himself12794-develops.com"
        }
    }

    version = "0.9-rev1"
    group = "com.himself12794" 
    archivesBaseName = "Heroes-Mod"

    minecraft {
        version = "1.8-11.14.3.1514"
        runDir = "run"
        mappings = "snapshot_20141130"
        // makeObfSourceJar = false 
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "com.himself12794:powersAPI:1.1-rev2"
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }

    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "sftp://himself1@ftp.himself12794-develops.com:18765"
            }
        }
    }

    processResources
    {
        inputs.property "version", project.version
        inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

        from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
            include 'mcmod.info'


            expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
        }

        from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
            exclude 'mcmod.info'
        }
    }
```

Any assistance anyone can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever fully solve this?  I'm facing a similar issue with Gradle+Maven+SFTP

Comment: @MarkKCowan if I remember correctly, I was able to circumvent the problem using a nightly build, though if you are experiencing the same problem, it may have snuck back into their builds

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved this specific problem yet, but I have discovered that the problem with the original maven plugin that caused me to try the maven-publish plugin was actually an issue with the current stable version of Gradle (2.7). Using the current nightly wrapper build has allowed me to circumvent this.